# Specflow test run as normal but steps in feature files do not turn back as those steps do not bind to methods

Tags: c#, .net, automated-tests, nunit, specflow

as the title of my question describe the problem. I have a test project with NUnit and Specflow. It build succesfully and run normally in work computer. 
However, when I clone to my computer, I can still build the project with no errors and all **the tests still run successfully** **but all the steps in Specflow feature files still have purple colour and do not turn black** (it indicate that those steps do not bind to any method). 
[image]
This problem does not happen with my work computer. I have installed all dependency in the projects and also install Specflow extension for Visual Studio but no cigar though.

Comment: Please, share your tests and project file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the tests run and the solution builds fine, this might be due to Visual Studio caching the step bindings. The solution is simple, but annoying:

1. Close all Visual Studio windows
2. Open a command prompt
3. Run this command: `del %TEMP%\*stepmap*`
4. Delete the `.vs` folder in the root directory of your solution
5. Restart Visual Studio and reload the solution

Comment: Thank man. it work . But I cant run the command rm %TEMP%\*stepmap* on my window. I dont know why so I have to clear all the temp folder by the command Del /S /F /Q %temp%